# Fisher information matrix of two parameter exponential distribution

Tags: exponential-distribution, fisher-information

Is it possible to find the Fisher Information matrix of the two parameter (scale and  location) exponential distribution?
Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the location parameter $\mu$ in the derivation in https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/263124/14346 and modifying the change of variable as $z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$, you can show that the information matrix  of for any location-scale distribution is of the form:
$$
I(\mu,\theta) = \frac{1}{\sigma^2} K_f
$$
where $K_f$ depends on the distribution.