# Obtaining the geometry of $\varphi_{\theta}(x)$ where the mean and variance are $\theta$-dependent

Tags: mathematical-statistics, exponential-family, fisher-information

Consider an (unnormalized) univariate distribution in the exponential family, which is in canonical form: $$\varphi_{\theta}(x)= \exp \bigg( \frac{\theta}{\log x} \bigg)$$ $x\in(0,1).$

$\varphi_{\theta}(x)$ is in the exponential family because it can be written in the form:

$$\varphi_{\theta}(x)= \exp\bigg( \eta(\theta)\cdot T(x) \bigg) $$

$T(x)=\frac{1}{\log x}$

$\eta(\theta)=\theta$

In the normal distribution, for example, you see the *mean* and *variance* listed explicitly in the probability distribution function, whereas $\theta$ in my distribution actually encodes both the mean and the variance and doesn't explicitly show them. This is because changing $\theta$ changes both the mean and the variance.

My goal is to be able to obtain the Fisher matrix so that I can write down the metric in terms of the parameters (which I think will correspond to hyperbolic geometry when viewed as a Riemannian manifold).

I've already calculated the mean and variance and they depend on $\theta$ so I am confused on how to derive the Fisher matrix if the mean and variance are coupled like this.

I've never run into a problem like this with any other distributions like the normal distribution, or Chi squared, etc.

**Question**: How do I "uncouple" the mean and variance in the distribution function $\varphi(x)?$ (I think it might not be possible).

I need a univariate 2-parameter distribution for $\varphi(x)$ and right now I only have a univariate 1-parameter distribution.

Answer (score 2):

You have misunderstood what the Fisher information is; it measures the amount of information a random variable $x$ contains about the parameter(s) of its associated distribution.  If you only have one parameter, then the Fisher information will be a single formula; if you have multiple parameters, it will be a matrix of formulae.

The Fisher information is equal to the variance of the derivative of the log-likelihood with respect to the parameter(s), which implies that the constant of integration cannot be ignored, as the parameter(s) will appear in it.  The derivative of the log-likelihood w.r.t. the parameter(s) is known as the *score* function.

In your case, a simple change of variable $y = - 1/\log x$, which changes the range from $(0,1)$ to $(0, \infty)$, will make things much easier for you:

$$f(y;\theta) = \theta \exp(-\theta y)$$

which is an Exponential distribution with mean $1/\theta$.  The log-likelihood is:

$$\mathcal{l}(\theta|y) = \log\theta -\theta y$$

which is clearly twice differentiable, allowing us to use the following expression for the Fisher information:

$$\mathcal{I}(\theta) = - \operatorname{E} \left[\left. \frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2} \log f(y;\theta) \,\, \right| \,\, \theta \right]$$

(All of this is on the Wikipedia page for [Fisher information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information).)

... and you should be able to solve for $\mathcal{I}(\theta)$ from here.

Comment: Ah okay so I can just figure out the Fisher metric for the 2-parameter exponential distribution and then apply the change of variables again

Comment: There is only one parameter for the exponential distribution.  You can see that by looking at the equation, as well as your original formulation.  Why are you so hung up on having two parameters?  Also, note that you are taking an expectation; there is no change of variable to perform after that's done.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/263131/218099

I would like 2-parameters in order to derive the underlying geometry in the sense of statistical manifolds. I can't achieve a surface with only one parameter

Comment: So when you make the change of variables, you are changing the distribution itself, which I don't want to do

Comment: 1. If I understand you correctly, you are trying to find a problem that you can "solve" (i.e., "derive the underlying geometry in the sense of statistical manifolds") in such a way that you have a surface.  Your original problem statement didn't allow you to do this, so you are abandoning it and searching for a new one, in this case, choosing a location-scale version of the Exponential distribution.... but 2) you don't want to change the distribution.  I don't see how you can reconcile these two objectives.

Comment: I haven't abandoned that approach. I could just define a 2-paramter distribution like this i suppose $$\varphi_{\theta \rho}(x)= \exp \bigg( \frac{\theta \rho}{\log x} \bigg)$$

Comment: That won't work; it should be clear that the parameters are not identifiable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147726/discussion-between-jbowman-and-geocalc33).